# Mysql SELECT value compare?

Tags: mysql

table like this:

```
-----------------------------
id    pid    key    value
-----------------------------
1      3    all     120
2      3    today   180
3      9    all     200
4      9    today   150
5      9    others   0
-----------------------------
```

how to

```
select * from table if all(120) < today(180) and if they have same pid(3)
```

I hope the result should be:

```
---------------------------
id    pid    key    value
---------------------------
1      3     all    120
2      3    today   180
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all entries for which another entry with all < today exists for the same pid

```
select t from table t where exists( 
    select * from table t2 where t.all < t2.today and t.pid = t2.pid
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t1.*
from yourtable t1
inner join (
    select *
    from yourtable
    group by pid
    having sum(if(`key` = 'all', `value`, 0)) < sum(if(`key` = 'today', `value`, 0))
) t2 on t1.pid = t2.pid
```

### SQLFiddle Demo